# Какой формат использует twitch и как такое реализовать для стриминга?

Tags: streaming, blob, трансляция, twitch

Здравствуйте.
На своём сайте я самостоятельно реализовал трансляции на nginx-rtmp, транслирую flv поток через флэш (часть клиентов через OBS), отдаю через флэш (для PC) и перекодирую его в HLS для мобилок через ffmpeg.

Пора мне убрать флэш хотя бы для воспроизведения видео. Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за формат современный blob:url используемый на twitch.tv, goodgame.ru и gaming.youtube.com ? 
И второй вопрос, хотя бы минимум как такое реализовать? Достаточно ли перекодировку добавить с flv на этот формат в ffmpeg или там технологии другие?

Очень сильно надеюсь на вашу помощь, я хочу тоже так уметь делать :) Единственная просьба не давайте ссылки на erlyvideo и wowza, там дают готовый продукт, а я хочу научиться сам с таким работать.

Большое спасибо :)